# How to swap images using media queries and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

Working on my site darrenbachan.com, when I click into a project, I like how the img works in desktop/laptop but when I get to mobile it doesn't really work. I either skip trying to fit my projects in devices and just have screenshots or I swap the images to make them look better on mobile.

My friend helped me set up the javascript:

```
var projects = {

        'project_1' : {
            'title' : 'EduTravel For Credit',
            'description' : 'Innovative travel for credit. Completely engage in your learning through exploration and discovery.',
            'images': [
                '/images/placeholder-1.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-2.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-3.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-4.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-5.gif'
            ],
            'more': 'even more'
        },

        'project_2' : {
            'title' : 'S-Trip!',
            'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'images': [
                '/images/s-trip/s-trip-1.jpg',
                '/images/s-trip/s-trip-1.jpg',
                '/images/s-trip/s-trip-1.jpg',
                '/images/s-trip/s-trip-1.jpg',
                '/images/s-trip/s-trip-1.jpg'
            ],
            'more': 'even more'
        },

        'project_3' : {
            'title' : 'Dayton 2 Daytona',
            'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'images': [
                '/images/placeholder-1.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-2.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-3.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-4.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-5.gif'
            ],
            'more': 'even more'
        },

        'project_4' : {
            'title' : 'Campus Vacations',
            'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'images': [
                '/images/placeholder-1.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-2.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-3.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-4.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-5.gif'
            ],
            'more': 'even more'
        },

        'project_5' : {
            'title' : 'Travel Wedding',
            'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'images': [
                '/images/placeholder-1.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-2.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-3.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-4.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-5.gif'
            ],
            'more': 'even more'
        },

        'project_6' : {
            'title' : 'Vibe Cancun',
            'description' : 'Lorem Ipsum',
            'images': [
                '/images/placeholder-1.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-2.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-3.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-4.gif',
                '/images/placeholder-5.gif'
            ],
            'more': 'even more'
        }

    }

    $('[data-type="projectLoader"]').click(function() { 

        var project = $(this).attr('data-project');

        var projectData = projects[project];

        $('#project-title').html(projectData.title);
        $('#project-description').html(projectData.description);
        $('#project-more').html(projectData.more);

        $('#project-images').empty('');

        $.each(projectData.images, function(item) { 
            $('#project-images').append('<div class="holder"><span class="image_holder" style="background-image:url('+projectData.images[item]+');"></span></div>')
        });

        $('article').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parents('article').addClass('active');

        $('body').toggleClass('projectLoaded');

        return false;

    });

    $('[data-type="projectDie"]').click(function() { 

        $('body').removeClass('projectLoaded');

        return false;

    });

    });
```

With the images being in javascript I am not sure how to accomplish what I want. Is it still possible to have the img swap once it reaches a mobile breakpoint?

Comment: Which images do you want to swap between?

Comment: Any image in here, I don't have the img that I want to swap it to.

Comment: I think you need to look into srcset. It's a relatively new feature that allows the browser to pick an image based on the width of its screen. More info here https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.